# Error starting Facebook Live with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, facebook

I need some help trying to stream an IPCAM to Facebook using ffmpeg.

I am using this command:

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -thread_queue_size 1024 -i rtsp://admin:inv243019@131.72.4.61:24300/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0 -f s16le -ar 48k -ac 1 -thread_queue_size 1024 -i pipe:0 -vf movie='http\:\/\/localhost\:9000\/storage\/images\/2\/avatar\/lwijf70iPGNXYuCF15rqEPEBYA3N65WJM33SWLdV.png', scale=160:-1[inner];[in][inner]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-(main_w*0.02):y=main_h*0.03 -threads 10 -vcodec libx264 -c:a aac -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*2) -reorder_queue_size 4000 -max_delay 10000000 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/4500974533305444?s_bl=1&s_psm=1&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=Abwvu8oZ-EaypT31`

This command is mixing an IPCAM with an audioSource captured by the browser, adding a logo with a video filter and outputting the result to Facebook.

Everything was working fine until yesterday and now when I start the command, the live video shows up on Facebook for a few seconds (6 ~ 15) and then ffmpegs throws an error and the stream is finished.

The resulting stream of 6 ~ 15 seconds still stays on my Facebook page, I can hear the audio, and everything seems ok.

The only problem is that ffmpeg keeps closing the stream.

Here is the ffmpeg output:

Stderr output: ffmpeg version N-92722-gf22fcd4483 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers

Stderr output:   built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181201
Stderr output:   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
Stderr output:   libavutil      56. 24.101 / 56. 24.101
Stderr output:   libavcodec     58. 42.102 / 58. 42.102
Stderr output:   libavformat    58. 24.101 / 58. 24.101
Stderr output:   libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
Stderr output:   libavfilter     7. 46.101 /  7. 46.101
Stderr output:   libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
Stderr output:   libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
Stderr output:   libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Stderr output: Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:inv243019@131.72.4.61:24300/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0':
Stderr output:   Metadata:
Stderr output:     title           : Media Server
Stderr output:   Duration: N/A, start: 0.236667, bitrate: N/A
Stderr output:     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 100 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
Stderr output: Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Stderr output: Input #1, s16le, from 'pipe:0':
Stderr output:   Duration: N/A, bitrate: 768 kb/s
Stderr output:     Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
Stderr output: Stream mapping:

Stderr output:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Stderr output:   Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Stderr output: [swscaler @ 000001f63fa2c300] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] using SAR=1/1
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] 264 - core 157 r2935 545de2f - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=10 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Stderr output: Output #0, flv, to 'rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/4500974533305444?s_bl=1&s_psm=1&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=Abwvu8oZ-EaypT31':
Stderr output:   Metadata:
Stderr output:     title           : Media Server
Stderr output:     encoder         : Lavf58.24.101
Stderr output:     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
Stderr output:     Metadata:
Stderr output:       encoder         : Lavc58.42.102 libx264
Stderr output:     Side data:
Stderr output:       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stderr output:     Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s
Stderr output:     Metadata:
Stderr output:       encoder         : Lavc58.42.102 aac
Stderr output: [Parsed_movie_0 @ 000001f63fb328c0] EOF timestamp not reliable
Stderr output: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
Stderr output: frame=   47 fps= 43 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=5 speed=   0x
Stderr output: frame=   75 fps= 47 q=29.0 size=     253kB time=00:00:00.61 bitrate=3349.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.384x
Stderr output: frame=  106 fps= 50 q=26.0 size=     311kB time=00:00:01.66 bitrate=1529.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.783x
Stderr output: frame=  122 fps= 46 q=29.0 size=     660kB time=00:00:02.16 bitrate=2492.1kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.824x
Stderr output: frame=  137 fps= 43 q=29.0 size=     678kB time=00:00:02.68 bitrate=2064.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.853x
Stderr output: frame=  153 fps= 42 q=29.0 size=     696kB time=00:00:03.20 bitrate=1781.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.875x
Stderr output: frame=  167 fps= 40 q=29.0 size=     712kB time=00:00:03.69 bitrate=1579.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.884x
Stderr output: frame=  184 fps= 39 q=29.0 size=    1048kB time=00:00:04.23 bitrate=2028.3kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.903x
Stderr output: frame=  199 fps= 38 q=29.0 size=    1066kB time=00:00:04.75 bitrate=1834.9kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.916x
Stderr output: frame=  214 fps= 38 q=29.0 size=    1083kB time=00:00:05.23 bitrate=1695.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.919x
Stderr output: [tls @ 000001f63f585400] Error in the push function.
Stderr output: av_interleaved_write_frame(): I/O error
Stderr output:     Last message repeated 1 times
Stderr output: [flv @ 000001f63f561480] Failed to update header with correct duration.
Stderr output: [flv @ 000001f63f561480] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
Stderr output: Error writing trailer of rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/4500974533305444?s_bl=1&s_psm=1&s_sw=0&s_vt=api-s&a=Abwvu8oZ-EaypT31: I/O error
Stderr output: frame=  221 fps= 35 q=29.0 Lsize=    1092kB time=00:00:05.48 bitrate=1631.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.862x
Stderr output: video:1037kB audio:48kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.671300%
Stderr output: [tls @ 000001f63f585400] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.
Stderr output:     Last message repeated 1 times
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] frame I:4     Avg QP:14.85  size:284559
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] frame P:56    Avg QP:16.82  size:  3908
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] frame B:161   Avg QP:25.06  size:   357
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] consecutive B-frames:  2.3%  0.9%  2.7% 94.1%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] mb I  I16..4: 36.5% 15.1% 48.4%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  P16..4:  7.5%  0.7%  1.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:90.3%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  5.2%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:94.8%  L0: 9.4% L1:90.6% BI: 0.0%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] 8x8 transform intra:15.6% inter:53.0%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 90.1% 0.7% 0.6% inter: 0.8% 0.0% 0.0%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] i16 v,h,dc,p: 18% 22% 48% 13%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 33% 20%  3%  2%  4%  4%  4%  6%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 29% 18%  4%  4%  4%  7%  3%  8%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] ref P L0: 85.9%  0.8%  9.4%  4.0%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] ref B L0: 70.7% 26.2%  3.1%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] ref B L1: 76.4% 23.6%
Stderr output: [libx264 @ 000001f63ff59040] kb/s:1536.22
Stderr output: [aac @ 000001f63f583600] Qavg: 331.232
Stderr output: Conversion failed!

Does anyone know what could cause this interruption an throw these errors?